# Почему не могу вызвать метод jQuery через $

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет! Обнаружил странную проблему. У меня есть jQuery плагин, который подключается таким вот образом

```
(function($){
  $.fn.plugin=function....
})(jQuery)
```

После чего он работает, только если вызывать метод через jQuery, при попытке сделать что-то типа `$('body').plugin()` выпадает

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).plugin is not a function

Comment: Какая у Вас версия jQuery? Как Вы подключаете скрипт вообще?

Comment: у меня 1.12.4 ..

Comment: например на странице использовано несколько версий jquery

Comment: Ну... Возможно и так, это ж wordpress